# How to Access Oauth 1.0 ?? I am working on SugarCrm

Tags: android, android-studio, oauth, sugarcrm

Hello everyone I am working on a CRM project which uses Sugarcrm 6.5 version. I wanted to know what kind of changes I have to do in my LoginActivity to get Token So that I can call it in other Activity.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button button;
private EditText editText;
private EditText editText2;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;
CheckBox show_password;
String user_fullname, email, user_id,user_mobile, session_id, module;

public LoginActivity(){


}

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    show_password = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.show_hide_password);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    // get the show/hide password Checkbox

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    //if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity

      //  Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      //  startActivity(intent);
       // finish();
  //  }
    // Login button Click Event

    show_password.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
            if (!isChecked) {
                // show password
                editText2.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            } else {
                // hide password
                editText2.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = editText2.getText().toString().trim();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(username, password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });
}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 */
private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String URL= "http://crm.sparshnow.com/api/index.php?username="+username+"&password="+password;
    final JsonObjectRequest strReq = new JsonObjectRequest(URL,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response);
            hideDialog();

            try {
                String success = response.getString("success");
                Log.d("response_value", success);
                if (success.equals("TRUE")) {

                    user_fullname=response.getString("user_fullname");
                    email=response.getString("email");
                    user_id=response.getString("user_id");
                    user_mobile=response.getString("user_mobile");
                    session_id=response.getString("session_id");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("user_fullname",user_fullname);
                    intent.putExtra("email",email);
                    intent.putExtra("user_mobile",user_mobile);
                    intent.putExtra("session_id", session_id);
                    session.setLogin(true);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Correct Detail ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError success) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + success.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            success.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(strReq);
}
private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

A little code 
and how to use it will be very useful for me.. please Help me